# How do I create a row of justified elements with fluid spacing using CSS?

Tags: css, cross-browser, fluid-layout, multiple-columns, justify

How do I create a row of block elements with auto widths using `text-align:justify`, `display: flex`, `column-count` and/or other CSS properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following components:

- A `text-align:justify` container for the row
- An `inline-block` container for each column
- An `inline-block` placeholder with `width:100%` to stretch the inside

`

```css
    /*Row container is justified*/
    #container { width: 100%; text-align: justify; }

    /*Column container and placeholder are inline-block*/
    object, span { display: inline-block; }

    /*Placeholder is stretched to enforce shrink-wrapping*/
    span { width: 100%; }
```

```html
 
      <!--row-->
      <div id="container">
        <!--column-->
        <object>
          <!--content-->
          <div>
          foo
          </div>
        </object>
        <object>
          <div>
          bar
          </div>
        </object>
        <object>
          <div>
          baz
          </div>
        </object>
        <object>
          <div>
          bop
          </div>
        </object>
        <object>
          <div>
          bip
          </div>
        </object>
        <!--placeholder-->
        <span></span>
      </div>
```

Or use a `text-align:justify` container with a nested `inline-block` and `column-count` row where `column-count` is a number equal to the number of child elements:

```css
#main, #container { width: 100%; }
#main { text-align: justify; }
#container { display:inline-block; } 
#container { -moz-column-count: 5; -webkit-column-count: 5; column-count: 5;}
```

```html
<!--full width container-->
<div id="main">

<!--justified inline-block row-->
  <div id="container">
     <!--columns-->
      <div>
      foo
      </div>
      <div>
      bar
      </div>
      <div>
      baz
      </div>
      <div>
      bop
      </div>
      <div>
      bip
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or a full-width container with `display:flex; flex-direction: row` and columns with `flex:auto`:

```css
#flex-container {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-direction: row;
 flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

#flex-container > .flex-item {
 -webkit-flex: auto;
 flex: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">Foo</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Bar</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Baz</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Bop</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Bip</div>
</div>
```

Or `display:grid` with `auto` for each column in `grid-template-columns` and `justify-content: space-between`:

```css
#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

```html
    <div id="grid-container">
        <div>Foo</div>
        <div>Bar</div>
        <div>Baz</div>
        <div>Bop</div>
        <div>Bip</div>
    </div>
```

Or `display: inline-grid` with `auto` for each column in `grid-template-columns` and `text-align: justify`:

```css
#grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
  }
```

```html
    <div id="grid-container">
        <div>Foo</div>
        <div>Bar</div>
        <div>Baz</div>
        <div>Bop</div>
        <div>Bip</div>
    </div>
```

> block-level element generates a principal block-level box that contains descendant boxes and generated content and is also the box involved in any positioning scheme.
>
> Some block-level elements may generate additional boxes in addition to the principal box: 'list-item' elements. These additional boxes are placed with respect to the principal box.
>
> non-replaced inline blocks and non-replaced table cells are block containers but not block-level boxes.
>
> Inline-level boxes that are not inline boxes (such as replaced inline-level elements, inline-block elements, and inline-table elements) are called atomic inline-level boxes because they participate in their inline formatting context as a single opaque box.
>
> When the total width of the inline-level boxes on a line is less than the width of the line box containing them, their horizontal distribution within the line box is determined by the 'text-align' property. If that property has the value 'justify', the user agent may stretch spaces and words in inline boxes (but not inline-table and inline-block boxes) as well.

**References**

- [CSS 2.1: Visual Formatting Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html)
- [Justify Grid](http://justifygrid.com/)
- [CSS Basic Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/)
- [CSSPlay: Basic Flex Box Holy Grail Layout with Sticky Footer](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/cssplay-flex-basic-layout.html)
- [CSS Features for Adaptive Layouts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2011/04/14/ie10-platform-preview-and-css-features-for-adaptive-layouts/)
- [Equidistant Objects with CSS | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/)
- [How to use CSS3 columns | Webdesigner Depot](https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/03/how-to-use-css3-columns/)
- [Difference between inline box and atomic inline box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557803/1113772)
- [What's the difference between a block-level box and a principal block-level box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114396/1113772)
- [Inline- and block-level boxes inside the block-container box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550554/1113772)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

- use the `text-align:justify` to the container;
- use the `:after` to the container;
- use `display:inline-block` to the column;
- add some break before at the last;

#### HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li class="break"></li>
  <li class="break"></li>
  <li class="break"></li>
  <li class="break"></li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
ul {
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;

  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 0.1px; /*hide whitespace between elements*/
}
ul:after{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: hsla(20,50%,85%,09);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px;

}
.break {
   height: 0;
}
```

please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/ovAtz).More details please click [here](http://www.w3cplus.com/css/text-align-justify-and-rwd.html).

Comment: In this case, the elements have a fixed width and height. The question is specific to fluid elements.

Comment: you can change the width for li element, eg: li {width: 20%}