# Block with "overflow: hidden" inside list item moves down on Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-lists, microsoft-edge

This can be observed with the code sample posted by Bilal Akil in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769248/list-with-nested-overflow-x-hidden-hides-list-counter-point-why-is-this-a-b):

http://jsfiddle.net/G46dK/

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <p>
            Moo
    <li>
        <p class="overflow-hidden">
            Moo
    <li>
        <p class="overflow-hidden">
            Moo
    <li>
        <p>
            Moo
</ol>
```

With the accompanying CSS:

```
p.overflow-hidden {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

On Edge, the content displays as follow, which looks like a bug to me:

[image: Display issues on Edge with overflow: hidden inside LI]

Any idea to have the content remaining on the same line as the list number when using `overflow: hidden` inside the `li`?

**[EDIT]**: **This question is about dealing with blocks with `overflow: hidden` inside a `LI`.** I do appreciate answers that try to work around the problem by moving the overflow outside of the block, but what I am really after is a solution that respects this constraint. You may also check this fiddle for a more advanced example: http://jsfiddle.net/G46dK/7

Comment: Does this do what you want?  http://jsfiddle.net/G46dK/11/

Comment: @user4749485 yes! Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making `.overflow-hidden { display: inline-block; }`? http://jsfiddle.net/G46dK/8

```
.overflow-hidden {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This displays as intended... unless if the text in the list is very long. In that case, overflow: hidden seems to be ignored: http://jsfiddle.net/G46dK/13/

Comment: Actually, adding width: 100% seems to do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/G46dK/14/ (needs to be tested on more browsers though)

Comment: OK I tested it working on Edge 14, IE11, FF49, Chrome 55 with width: 100%. @Michael Coker: please amend your response, so I can accept it.