# Inline- and block-level boxes inside the block-container box

Tags: html, css

In the CSS spec in sec [9.2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes) said:

> Except for table boxes, which are described in a later chapter, and
>   replaced elements, a block-level box is also a block container box. A
>   block container box either contains only block-level boxes or
>   establishes an inline formatting context and thus contains only
>   inline-level boxes.
>   Consider the markup:

```
<div id="d">
    <div>Anonymous text</div>
    <span>Some text</span>
    <span>Another some text</span>
    <div>Another anonymous text</div>
</div>
```

and styles:

```
div#d{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: aqua;
}
```

In my case `div#d` contains block-level and inline-level boxes. But in the sec. [9.2.1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level) said that

> if a block container box (such as that generated for the DIV above)
>   has a block-level box inside it (such as the P above), then we force
>   it to have only block-level boxes inside it.

Q: Why we can put inside the block-level element (e.g. `div`) both inline and block elements and they will displayed as inline and block element, but in spec said that block container box either contains only block-level boxes or establishes an inline formatting context and thus contains only inline-level boxes.

I'm confused. Can you dispel my doubts?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @SalmanA I'm update my question.

Comment: From what i understand: the specs say that if a box contains a mix of inline and block elements then inline elements are wrapped in an anonymous block to satisfy the "only block or only inline" clause.

Answer (score 4):

The spec goes on to say:

> The line boxes before the break and after the break are enclosed in anonymous block boxes, and the block-level box becomes a sibling of those anonymous boxes

So the inline elements are wrapped in "anonymous blocks" (generated by the CSS engine in the browser, and  invisible to your DOM inspector), that are block-level, and all children of the container are therefore block-level, instead of a mix of block- and inline-elements.

Comment: But why this anonymous blocks doesnt starting with a new line? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8BSs/6/) .

Comment: That will depend on the styling -- the divs, perhaps, are floated? If the first div is floated, it will sit alongside the spans. the spans, themselves, are both enclosed in 1 anonymous block (if I've read the spec correctly), so there's no problem with them running together inline.