# Difference between inline box and atomic inline box

Tags: html, css

Consider the following code:

```
<div></div>

div{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

div block is generated atomic inline-level box now. As said in [spec. 9.2.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes)

> Inline-level boxes that are not inline boxes (such as replaced
>   inline-level elements, inline-block elements, and inline-table
>   elements) are called atomic inline-level boxes because they
>   participate in their inline formatting context as a single opaque box.

What does 'opaque' mean in this case? Is inline boxes participated in the inline formatting context as a transparent box?

So I'm interested in what difference between atomic inline-level box and inline box?

Answer (score 3):

From the WC3 CSS2.1 Specification, Chapter [9 Visual formatting model:](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#inline-boxes)

> An inline box is one that is both inline-level and whose contents
>   participate in its containing inline formatting context. **A
>   non-replaced element with a 'display' value of 'inline' generates an
>   inline box**.
>
> **Inline-level boxes that are not inline boxes (such as
>   replaced inline-level elements, inline-block elements, and
>   inline-table elements) are called atomic inline-level** boxes because
>   they participate in their inline formatting context as a single opaque
>   box.

**Therefore**

- Elements with `display: inline` generates *inline boxes*.
- Elements with `display: inline-table | inline-block` and replaced inline-level elements (like `<img>`) generates *inline-level atomic boxes*.

With regards to your question on what `opaque` means, @BoltClock explains it in a great way here:

[CSS Spec - Atomic Inline Level Boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537565/css-spec-atomic-inline-level-boxes)

> **Opaque** means that the box is a singular, solid unit, and that it
>   cannot be split across lines like an inline box can when its text
>   cannot all fit on a single line.

---

## And here is some additional detail from me, that might help

**Inline-level boxes includes boxes...**

- ...whose content participate in its containing inline formatting context

  - These are called *inline boxes*
  - They are generated by elements with `display: inline`
  - Note the words "*...whose content participate in its containing...*". This means that inline-level child elements inside this *inline-level box*, are in the same *inline formatting context* as the parent. This, in turn, means that the individual child *inline-level elements* will separate and fall to a new line if there is white space (and the `white-space` property is not changed). In effect, the parent *inline box* will split into several boxes. Here, all the *inline-level elements* inside the parent *inline box*, live in one big happy *inline formatting context*.
- ...that participate in their *inline formatting context* as a single opaque box

  - These are called *atomic inline-level boxes*
  - They are generated by elements with `display: inline-table | inline-block | inline-flex | inline-grid`
  - Opaque means that the box is one single solid box
  - A consequence of that is that the box cannot be split, even if *inline-level boxes* inside it normally should fall to the next line
  - Instead, scrollbars would appear
  - Contents inside this *atomic inline-level box* does not participate in the same *inline formatting context* as its parent

And finally, as seen, *inline-level boxes* is a super-set of *inline boxes*.

Hope that helps someone in the future.

Comment: Not just inline-table and inline-block, but inline-flex and inline-grid are also atomic.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. Referring to [Visual Formatting Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html)

```
<p>Some <em>emphasized</em> text</p>
```

> anonymous inline boxes inherit inheritable properties from their
>   block parent box. Non-inherited properties have their initial value.
>   In the example, the color of the anonymous inline boxes is inherited
>   from the P, but the background is transparent

Comment: How does anonymous blocks relation to my question? I'm interested in difference between atomic inline-level box and inline box.

Comment: The normal inline boxes are mentioned as anonymous inline boxes.