# Contradiction in Definition of Inline-Level Boxes and Inline Boxes (W3C)

Tags: html, css, w3c

[W3C source for the quotes below.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#inline-boxes)

> The following values of the 'display' property make an element
>   *inline-level*: 'inline', 'inline-table', and 'inline-block'

Thus, an element with `display: inline-block` is an *inline-level element*.

> *Inline-level elements* generate *inline-level boxes*, which are boxes
>   that participate in an *inline formatting context*.

Thus, all *inline-level boxes* participate in an *inline formatting context*.

> An inline box is one that is both inline-level and whose contents
>   participate in its containing inline formatting context

If all *inline-level boxes* participate in an *inline formatting context*, and an *inline box* is one that is both an *inline-level box* and participates in an *inline formatting context*, it must be true that all *inline-level boxes* are *inline boxes*, and vice versa.

And finally, here comes the statement that then breaks the logic:

> Inline-level boxes that are not inline boxes (such as replaced
>   inline-level elements, inline-block elements, and inline-table
>   elements) are called atomic inline-level boxes...

In other words:

First we are told, via logical implication, that all *inline-level boxes* are *inline boxes*. Then, we are told the opposite: That several *inline-level boxes* (like those generated by elements with `display: inline-block`), are in fact **not** *inline boxes*.

Am I missing something or are the quotes contradicting each other?

---

### EDIT

- I found the following post by @BoltClock, which is really good: [CSS Spec - Atomic Inline Level Boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537565/css-spec-atomic-inline-level-boxes)
- I also posted an answer to another question, after understanding the whole concept a bit better. It can be found here: [Difference between inline box and atomic inline box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557803/difference-between-inline-box-and-atomic-inline-box/50278605#50278605)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not a contradiction in the standard, but we have to read carefully to spot the differences.

1. Inline-level boxes are boxes that participate in an inline formatting context.
2. An inline box is a inline-level box whose **contents** participate in its containing inline formatting context

A span-element inside a paragraph is an inline box, because the text inside the span-element participate in the paragraphs' surround content.

An element with `display: inline-block;` will flow with surrounding content as if it were a single inline box, but since this element actually will generate a **block element box**, the elements contents do not participate in its containing inline formatting context.

Comment: Thanks, that's right. I added two links to the bottom of my OP, that will hopefully help others in the future. The second link is an answer I just posted myself, to another similar question (after understanding the concept a bit better). It covers some of the points you raise in this answer.