# What exactly is an inline box?

Tags: html, css, w3c

https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css2/#inline-boxes

> An inline box is one that is both inline-level and whose contents
> participate in **its containing inline formatting context**.
> A non-replaced element with a display value of inline generates an
> inline box. Inline-level boxes that are not inline boxes (such as
> replaced inline-level elements, inline-block elements, and
> inline-table elements) are called atomic inline-level boxes because
> they participate in their inline formatting context as a single opaque
> box.

I quoted the specification but I don't understand the part **marked in bold**.

Could you give me an example of `inline box` and an example of something that is not `inline box`?

I especially need **details of the part marked in bold**, please.

Comment: "_Could you give me an example and an example of one that is not `inline box`?_": This seems like a typo/incomplete question. Can you update it?

Comment: hi @jsejcksn ready, I updated, thank you in advance

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557803/difference-between-inline-box-and-atomic-inline-box?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between inline box and atomic inline box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557803/difference-between-inline-box-and-atomic-inline-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have HTML like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <span>Hello world</span>
      <img href="example.com" alt="an example">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: A depiction of a DOM Document on the left and the Box tree it generates on the right]

From this we can see that the box created by the `<span>` inline box, its "Hello world" text content and the `<img>` inline-level box participate in inline formatting context established by the `<div>` element

Comment: HI @Alohci in the div you put "*creates a block box and a root inline box*", it is for when the block container has `inline elements` and `block-level elements`, right?

Comment: I don't understand that part as the div only has `inline` elements @Alohci

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer - The div will establish an inline formatting context and create a root inline box only if it has inline-level elements and no block level elements. If the div contains both inline level elements and block level elements we get a more complex arrangement where the div creates additional anonymous block boxes to contain the inline level elements.

Comment: Hi @Alohci +1. So, in this example you put, the `span` and the `img` are `inline boxes` because they participate in the inline formatting context **that is containing them**, since the `div` creates an inline formatting context because there are only `inline-level elements`, right?

Comment: that is, the `div` is creating an inline formatting context, right? @Alohci

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer - Yes. Although if we're being really precise we should be careful about referring to formatting contexts _containing_ boxes. A formatting context isn't really an area of the canvas in which boxes are painted, but a _set of rules_ that control how the descendant boxes are laid out. The distinction usually doesn't matter, but I have known it to cause confusion, and since you highlight those words, I think it's worth mentioning.