# How to make perfect columns with equal padding with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to replicate columns with equal padding using flexbox, they need to be as seen on this image:

[image]

The lighter gray box is invisible, the padding between boxes should be equal, but the side boxes should have no padding on the side that's not touching any box. Before, I would do something like:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
    width: 32%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.box:nth-of-type(3n - 1){
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
```

And then for making them responsive I would add a breakpoint and remove the left and right margins, set the width to 49% for example and then add a margin-left with 2% to the nth-of-type(2n).

How can I replicate this with flexbox? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `justify-content:space-between`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a row of justified elements with fluid spacing using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027385/how-do-i-create-a-row-of-justified-elements-with-fluid-spacing-using-css)